# C++ prints strange character from recursive function

Tags: c++, string, char, character, cout

I want to create a function such that given a string, put '*' between each char.

e.g:

hello ---> h*e*l*l*o

```
using namespace std;

string allStar(string str, int n)
{

    if (str.at(n + 1) == '.') {

        return string(1, str.at(n));
    }

    return str.at(n) + "*" + allStar(str, n + 1);
}

int main()
{

    string str;

    cout << "Input word: ";
    cin >> str;

    str = str + ".";

    cout << allStar(str, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Input word: hello

Then I get:
�������o

Comment: `return string(1, str.at(n));` - what is `n` here? What ensures it is within bounds of `str`?

Comment: You need to work on your code formatting...

Comment: I added a '.' at the end of the string to work as base case on main.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: "I added a '.' at the end of the string to work as base case on main" - And that fixes anything *how*?

Comment: You need to use the index parameter to check if it is at the last element in the array. You do that by checking `n == str.size() - 1`. Your other problem is explained by Igor. The solution to that is to create a `std::string` first and append to that since `std::string` already has functional string concatenation built in. https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f16ab0e29539179

Comment: @JesperJuhl Well, it does...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - an explanation of *how* would be great..

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - What I can or cannot figure out is irrelevant. My point is that OP should be provided with a proper explanation. Besides, I do not believe I berated OP (at least not intentionally).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.at(n) + "*"` means "take a pointer to string literal `"*"`, and offset it by the number that happens to be an ASCII code of the character `str.at(n)`". Your program then exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing index out of bounds.

Comment: Hello Igor, what happens is that I'm new working on C++, could you explain to me a little bit more (?), I understand kind of your point, and it seems convincing, and it is not accessing index out of bounds, look at main.

Comment: `"*"` is a `char*` pointer (let's call it `p`) to an array of two characters, `{'*' , '\0'}`. So say, `p+0` points to the star character, and `p+1` points to the terminating NUL. 0 and 1 are the only valid offsets into this two-element array. Now `p+'h'` is equivalent to `p+104`; character literal `'h'` stands for the ASCII code of the corresponding character, which happens to be 104. This is advancing the pointer way past its bounds, into some random memory. So is `'h' + p`; addition is commutative, even for pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Finally, you are implicitly constructing `std::string` from that garbage pointer, which produces a string containing garbage characters.

Comment: You can use ""s literal (by adding s after ") to use string instead of char*.